# Measuring performance for keras model being trained in batches

Tags: python, pandas, validation, keras, deep-learning

I have a keras model which i am trying to train with a large dataset in chunks

```py
for chunk in pd.read_csv(input_file, chunksize=chunk_size, usecols = FEATURE_COLUMNS, low_memory = False):

       (X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val,full_pipeline) = dataPrep.get_data(data=chunk, mean=mean, variance=variance)



       print("Clicks in Training Set =>  {} , in CV =>  {}".format(np.sum(y_train == 1),np.sum(y_val == 1)))
       print("SMS in Training Set =>  {} , in CV =>  {}".format(np.sum(y_train == 0),np.sum(y_val == 0)))

       preprocessor = full_pipeline
       model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
       score = model.evaluate(X_val, y_val, verbose=0)

       print('Validation Metrics    :', score)
```

Is there any way to measure the f1 score of the model after training on the entire dataset? Instead of performance of each chunk

Answer (score -1):

Hi there writing my suggestion here because I'm not able to comment...

correct me if I'm wrong but you could just get the f1-score after every chunk and then after the training is done you could get the mean of the gathered f1-scores.

Alernatively you also could get the recall and precision for every chunk and then use them in the final formular for the f1-score([Formular look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score))

To see how to implement the f1-score, recall and precision you could take a look [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/45165/how-to-get-accuracy-f1-precision-and-recall-for-a-keras-model)

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I dont think this is a good way to measure the performance, I tried it but i am not satisfied with the answer

Comment: I'm sorry that this is not the answer that you are looking for. I read your question again...if you just want to measure the f1-score after the whole model is trained you could do the evaluation on the validation dataset outside the loop. This way you get the f1 score for the whole model.